# PHP Looping through a multimentional array like this

Tags: php, arrays

Ok, so it's nearly 2 hours I've been trying, and I seem to be going nowhere with this loop.

This is my array and loop I was trying:

```
$categories = array (
    "US01" => array("name" => "Audio & Video", "alias" => "audio-video"),
    "US02" => array("name" => "Books", "alias" => "books"),
    "US03" => array("name" => "Toys", "alias" => "toys"),
    "US04" => array("name" => "Computer Hardware", "alias" => "comp-hard"),
);

$keys = array_keys($categories);
$c = count($keys);

for( $i = 0; $i < $c; $i++ ) {
    echo( $categories[$i] );
    echo '<br>';
}
```

How in the world do I get results like this:

```
US01 Audio & Video
US02 Books
US03 Toys
US04 Computer Hardware
```

I'm looking to get the key and name. I can print the key, but how is getting what's inside that done?

Comment: Loop through the array using a `foreach` loop. Print the key and the sub-array value: `foreach ($categories as $key => $sub) {  echo $key.' '.$sub['name'].PHP_EOL; }` — See [demo](https://eval.in/154199).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using a [`foreach`](http://php.net/foreach) will make this much simpler:

```
foreach ($categories as $key=>$value) {
    echo $key." ".$value["name"]."<br>";

    //alternatively
    printf("%s %s<br>", $key, $value["name"]);
}
```

If you insist on using [`for`](http://php.net/for), it should work like this:

```
$keys = array_keys($categories);
$c = count($keys);

for( $i = 0; $i < $c; $i++ ) {
    echo $keys[$i]." ".$categories[$keys[$i]]["name"]."<br>";
}
```

You cannot use `$categories[$i]` as the key is not numeric but is set in `$keys[$i]`

Answer (score 1):

Simple as that, use [foreach](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)

```
foreach ($categories as $key=>$value) {
    echo "$key {$value['name']}<br/>";
}
```